# How to switch from yuyv422 to yuv420p for better framerate in ffmpeg on Windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg, logitech

I upgraded PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10, as it is discontinued. Problem is,
I had low latency monitoring and recording solution with FFmpeg.

After the upgrade, Logitech camera switched from yuv420p to yuyv422 and I lost 30 fps support at 1280x720. Now it is only limited to 10 FPS.

Tried different drivers, it still yuyv422

Here is a code i use.

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel panic -hwaccel qsv -threads 1 -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -strict experimental -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 10 -pixel_format yuyv422 -i video="C922 Pro Stream Webcam" -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 24 -tune zerolatency -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 dvr_%%04d.avi -codec:v copy -f nut - | ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos -window_title "kamera" -noborder -left 1920 -top 150 -fast -framedrop -
```

I really need low CPU, no latency monitoring at minimum 24 FPS and recording capabilities. File size doesn't matter so much.

Using mjpeg eats CPU like crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I force installed old Logitech driver and get back yuv420p/30FPS support.
I store some instructions and drivers here: https://github.com/mjasnikovs/logitechC920-vlc
Maybe somebody will find it useful.

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.